# DIY Leather engraving

Tags: leather, carving

Is there a way to engrave or carve words into leather without the use of professional engraving or stamping tools?

I want to make one similar to the one in the picture, but can not find the kit to do so anywhere in my local stores.
I read somewhere that it could be done by heated knife but I'm not sure. Any help, please?

(Any link to a tutorial would be appreciated, too)

[image]

Comment: Engraving that precise may be done with a laser, which I assume falls under "professional"?

Comment: @Erica, Laser cutters are available to hobbyists in a lot of locations via maker spaces and even in some libraries.  Many maker spacers have community nights where non-members can use the tools under member guidance either for free or for a small fee.   Laser cutters are now a consumer level tool.  Professionals use plasma-jets and water cutters.

Comment: I'm leaving it up to Bella whether she considers that professional grade or not. The additional context in her question implies she wants leather working tools that she can buy for herself, at a reasonable price, but she'll need to edit to clarify.

Comment: @Erica I have mentioned in the question that the tools are not available in my local stores, I am not from US.

Comment: @BellaSwan - If basic leather working tools are not available, I am not sure you are going to be able to work with leather in the way you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[image: Image from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drehmesser_und_Punziereisen_-_Swivel_Knife.jpg)[1]]

Traditionally engraving like this would be done with a [swivel knife](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swivel_knife) - these will generally cost a few pounds or dollars, so are much more affordable than a laser engraver. They do take a bit of skill to use, so I would suggest practising on some offcuts first.

You can find tutorials on swivel knife usage all over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The one in the picture appears to be laser engraved, so I assume that that is infeasible. You could get a similar result more easily if you tried to brand it, but that still requires your design to be shaped out of metal and then heated really hot. If you really want the professional look, I would suggest just buying a leather stamp online.

Comment: Could you use a tool similar to the one used for wood burning as well? Or is that the same as what is used for branding?